# Считывание текста из поля виджета QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qtextedit

В программке на *Python 3* с использованием *PyQt5* есть проблема со считыванием текста с текстового поля виджета `QTextEdit`.

Прошу помочь разобраться. Текст вводится с клавиатуры или вставляется с буфера обмена.

Надо считать текст в переменную при нажатии на кнопку с названием в коде `pushButton` и вывести ее в консоль.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
# Импортируем наш шаблон.
from pp import Ui_MainWindow
 
 
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
```

**pp.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 140, 104, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        mytext = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copy_text)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def copy_text(self):
         text = self.textEdit.text()
         print(text)
```

Answer (score 3):

> QString QTextEdit::toPlainText() const
>
> Возвращает текст редактирования текста в виде простого текста.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# Импортируем наш шаблон.
#from pp import Ui_MainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 140, 104, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        mytext = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copy_text)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def copy_text(self):
         text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()         # <---   - text()   +++ toPlainText
         print(text)
         
         
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = mywindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]